# Unable to connect a server with FTP and PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am unable to connect to a FTP server when i am connecting it through our PHP code. Most embarrassing thing is that i get only false when trying to connect server with ftp_connect() method. No errors are reported. This is my first time when i am working with FTP in PHP. if anyone who have previously worked on it can help me out here. Here is my code :

```
/* Source File Name and Path */    
$remote_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/some-folder/file.txt";

/* New file name and path for this file */
$ftp_host = 'ftp://targetserver.com/some folder/'; 
$ftp_user_name = 'user';
$ftp_user_pass = 'XXXXX';

/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = 'ftp://targetserver.com/some-folder/file.txt';

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host, 21);
var_dump($connect_it);

/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Download $remote_file and save to $local_file */
if ( ftp_get( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
     echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

Comment: do you get any error message? If so please post it. Otherwhise, have you checked the user rights? maybe you don´t have write permissions with the user executing the script.

Comment: @Michael, No i am not getting any error message related to FTP. I double checked my error log. User rights are also fine with enough permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually getting false means that your ftp client couldn't connect to the server for some reason

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
```

The best to do before you dive into php debugging is to try out another ftp client such as https://filezilla-project.org/ and see if all works fine, if not you will have saved your time because the issue not coming from your php script.

> UPDATE 1

Then try this:

```
$ftp_host = 'targetserver.com';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php#refsect1-function.ftp-connect-parameters

```
The FTP server address. This parameter shouldn't have any trailing slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://.
```

And as for local_file and remote_file, they must be paths and not urls
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php#refsect1-function.ftp-get-examples

Comment: I have already tried this before writing script. Server is connecting and working fine with FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks @smarber, this solution worked out perfectly. But what to do in the case when we do not have the root access to the FTP and we have access to only it's one of the folder like 'targetserver.com/some-folder/'? Please advise.

Comment: Use absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

As ftp_connect function doesn't produce an error, I assume the extension is installed.
It is very possible this could be a firewall issue with port 21 blocked. (This is a very common reason)

Comment: Ok Denis, makes sense. Should i check this port at my server or the opposite server or both server port should be open?

Comment: Regarding the FTP server itself. if you can connect to it using an FTP client, like filezilla from your desktop, there is nothing to do on this side. Regarding the server where the PHP code is, you need to make sure that you can use the port 21, but it won't be good enough as the FTP protocol uses several ports for file transfers. What kind of webserver are you using? Where is it hosted for now?

Comment: I complete my comment: if you have the hands on the FTP server and if you want to limit the number of ports you want to open on your webserver, you can configure the FTP server to use a certain number of ports or even a range of ports (for file transfers, for connecting to the FTP server only, the port 21 is used)

Comment: smarber is right. You need first to amend the FTP address as per the PHP documentation.

Comment: Thanks Denis, for this useful information. Really appreciated. I've asked smarber another issue which is common. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
      Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

$ftp_server = "94.23.x.xxx";
$ftp_username   = "anxxxxx";
$ftp_password   =  "6xxxxxxxx";

// setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$remote_file_path = "/JustForTest".$file;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
        FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";

?>
```

Then what's the problem with the above code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).